# convert indented text to multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Convert indented text to multi dimensional array in php. I have tried some examples for indenting
text to PHP multi dimensional array but to no avail. Here is what I did so far. The first text in string has no indent and after that 3 space indents and so on.

```
<?php

function convertIndentedTextToArray($text) {
    $lines = explode("\n", $text);
    $result = [];
    $stack = [];
    
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $indent = 0;
        while (substr($line, 0, 1) === " ") {
            $indent++;
            $line = substr($line, 1);
        }
        
        $node = ['value' => trim($line), 'children' => []];
        
        while ($indent < count($stack)) {
            array_pop($stack);
        }
        
        if (empty($stack)) {
            $result[] = &$node;
        } else {
            $parent = &$stack[count($stack) - 1];
            $parent['children'][] = &$node;
        }        
        $stack[] = &$node;
    }
    
    return $result;
}
```

I also tried this example

```
$string = <<<EOT
Hey again I am on root
   Hey it's wonderful
  This is good time
  I love the way you are
Hey again I am on root  
EOT;

$lines = explode("\n", $string);
$output = [];
$currentNode = &$output;

$indent1 = 1;
$elementIndex = 0; // Initialize index for ManagedElements

$hold = [];
$cnt=0;$cnt2=0;
$incre=1;

$first=0;
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $trimmedLine = trim($line);
    $indentationLevel = strlen($line) - strlen($trimmedLine);

    if ($indentationLevel == 0) {
        $elementIndex++; // Increment index for each new ManagedElement
        $hold[$elementIndex]['parent'][] = trim($line);

    } else if ($indentationLevel == 3) {
        $hold[$elementIndex]['parent']['child'][] = trim($line);
        $cnt=count($hold[$elementIndex]['parent']['child'])-$incre;
    } else if ($indentationLevel == 6) {
        $hold[$elementIndex]['parent']['child']['child'][$cnt][] = trim($line);
        $cnt2=count($hold[$elementIndex]['parent']['child']['child'])-$incre;
    }
    else if ($indentationLevel == 9) {
        $hold[$elementIndex]['parent']['child']['child']['child'][$cnt2][] = trim($line);
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($hold);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Input:**

```
$input = "Hello world I am good
 Hey it's wonderful
  This is good time
   I love the way you are
Hey again I am on root";
```

But I am getting output with children array blank:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'value' => 'Hey again I am on root',
    'children' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'value' => 'Hey again I am on root',
    'children' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
)
```

This is the **expected output:**

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'value' => 'Hey again I am on root',
    'children' => 
    array (
      'value'=>'Hey it's wonderful',
      'children'=>array()
    ),
    array (
      'value'=>'This is good time',
      'children'=>array('value'=>'I love the way you are','children'=>array())
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'value' => 'Hey again I am on root',
    'children' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: I am newbie sorry for formatting issues brother.

Comment: So what is the intended result, _exactly_?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => Hey again I am on root [children] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Array ( [value] => Hey again I am on root [children] => Array ( ) ) )
 but It legs children array blank ... it should include children array 'This is good time' and its child  I love the way you are

Comment: @NarendraSharma Please add the var_export() of the expected result in your question itself.

Comment: @NarendraSharma Is that your expected output?

Comment: No My problem is that It should include child nodes.. yes output should be like var_export but should include child array

Comment: @NarendraSharma Yes, so you would need to show the entire correct output to us. Your current expected output is incomplete.

Comment: Not sure but I need parent and child relationship.. with indent as parent if its has children add children .. and keys should be numeric

Comment: @NarendraSharma We need a correct manually written output in your question to get a hang of what the question is in the first place. Can't you manually write the correct expected output for your given input?

Comment: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'value' => 'Hey again I am on root',
    'children' => 
    array (
      'value'=>'Hey it's wonderful',
      'children'=>array()
    ),
    array (
      'value'=>'This is good time',
      'children'=>array('value'=>'I love the way you are','children'=>array())
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'value' => 'Hey again I am on root',
    'children' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
) this is the expected output

Comment: added expected output

Comment: @NarendraSharma Got it now. Why `Hey again I am on root'` should be there twice in the result?

Comment: @NarendraSharma Yes but we have already included it at level 0(first level), isn't it? Why consider it again?

Comment: as Its multi dimentaional array .  I have given text just for example. It could be anything ,,, Just need to detect if there is 3 space .. then make children of it and previous array is the parent of children .. hope you got my point.

Comment: @NarendraSharma Hmm.. It is trickier than using just a stack.

Comment: Are you unable to do it ? .. you have a good repu. still you cant do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254844/discussion-between-nice-dev-and-narendra-sharma).

Comment: @Nar your first snippet looks like ChatGPT output.  Does this work for your real application data? https://3v4l.org/7asJj

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have made this dynamic with respect to spaces.

The way I have done it is to

- Not use stack like structure since the copy by value and copy by reference can create clumsy code and would be quite unreadable with respect to what sits in the stack and what goes into the final result.
- calculate the no. of leading spaces in the string.
- Go to the deeply nested kid or child array till leading spaces' times and find the correct child to add the current text or line to.
- While traversing, always find the last kid of the current array since that is where the current one is going to be added to.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$input = <<<EOT
Hello world I am good
 Hey it's wonderful
  This is good time
   I love the way you are
Hey again I am on root
EOT;

$d = array_filter(explode("\n", $input));

$result = [];

foreach($d as $line){
    $leadingSpaces = strlen($line) - strlen(ltrim($line));
    
    $currKid = &$result;
    
    while($leadingSpaces-- > 0){
        if(empty($currKid['children'])){
            $currKid = &$currKid['children'];
        }else{
            $currKid = &$currKid['children'][count($currKid['children']) - 1];
        }
    }
    
    $currKid['children'][] = [
        'value' => $line,
        'children' => []
    ];
}

$result = $result['children'] ?? []; // remove "children" key from first level if desired.

print_r($result);
```

[**Live Demo**](https://3v4l.org/uLKOP)

Comment: Use strspn($line, ' ') to get the indentation. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strspn.php

Comment: @lukas.j Not required or can be an alternative since this question only cares about leading spaces to judge the hierarchy

Comment: this solution assumes the change in indentation is always 1

Comment: @krisgjika What do you mean by that? It calculates leading spaces correctly!

Comment: @nice_dev https://3v4l.org/g3a7B if I add another space to the deepest row the structure "breaks"

Comment: @nice_dev That is what strspn($line, ' ') is doing: it gives you the length of the indentation.

Comment: @krisgjika Yes because you are trying to have a 5th child without having a 4th parent. The symmetry needs to be maintained for a proper hierarchy.

Comment: @lukas.j Agreed but I am just fine with my subtraction for now.

Comment: your code is ok but one problem .. my string text  indented only three space fixed.. and your string has indent to only 1 space when add more space upto 3 ... it created blank children... so indent is fixed 3 space only for children .. so modify it please

Comment: @NarendraSharma Can you share an online link example?

Comment: its perfect after this little modification if(!empty($currKid['children'])) {
    $currKid = &$currKid['children'];
   } thanks

Comment: Its yet not perfect.. I tried with different data.. I will tell details later on this thread

Comment: @NarendraSharma Can you share an online fiddle link to demonstrate your example? Please don't drag this for long.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was over-cluttered, but basically your string wasn't presented in the same format that the code requires, i.e. a multiple of 3 leading spaces and no trailing spaces.

```
    <?php
    
    $string = <<<EOT
    Hey again I am on root
       Hey it's wonderful
       This is good time
          I love the way you are
    Hey again I am on root
    EOT;
    
    $lines = explode("\n", $string);
    $output = [];
    $elementIndex = 0; // Initialize index for ManagedElements
           
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $trimmedLine = trim($line);
        $indentationLevel = strlen($line) - strlen($trimmedLine);
    
        if ($indentationLevel == 0) {
            $elementIndex++; // Increment index for each new ManagedElement
            $output[$elementIndex]['parent'][] = trim($line);
        } else if ($indentationLevel == 3) {
            $output[$elementIndex]['parent']['child'][] = trim($line);
        } else if ($indentationLevel == 6) {
            $output[$elementIndex]['parent']['child']['child'][] = trim($line);
        }
        else if ($indentationLevel == 9) {
            $output[$elementIndex]['parent']['child']['child']['child'][] = trim($line);
        }
    }
    
    print_r($output);
```

(https://www.tehplayground.com/zmiKIdTfNqXapTaP)

produces

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [parent] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Hey again I am on root
                    [child] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Hey it's wonderful
                            [1] => This is good time
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => I love the way you are
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [parent] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Hey again I am on root
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: When you run this code with this string you got to know error .. try this string Hey again I am on root
   Hey it's wonderful
   Hey it's wonderful2
      this is yet another child
   This is good time
      I love the way you are
Hey again I am on root

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to trim ending spaces before comparing `strlen($line) - strlen($trimmedLine)`, as `strlen('Hey I am on root ') != strlen(trim('Hey I am on root '))`

I have also added a new key in your structure to simplify the logic.

```php
<?php
$string = <<<EOT
Hey I am on root
 Hey it's wonderful
  This is good time
  I love the way you are
Hey again I am on root  
EOT;

$lines = explode("\n", $string);
$lines = array_map('rtrim', $lines);
$out = [];
$iter = 0;

foreach($lines as $row => $line) {
    $trimmedLine = trim($line);

    if (strlen($line) - strlen($trimmedLine) === 0) {
        $iter = $row;
        $out[$row] = ['value' => $trimmedLine, 'identation' => 0, 'children' => []];
        continue;
    }
    
    $out[$iter]['children'] = findChild($out[$iter], $trimmedLine, strlen($line) - strlen($trimmedLine));
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($out);
echo "</pre>";

function findChild(array $data, $value, int $identation) {
    if (empty($data['children'])) {
        $data['children'][] = ['value' => $value, 'identation' => $identation, 'children' => []];
        return $data['children'];
    }
    
    foreach($data['children'] as $index => $child) {
        
        if ($child['identation'] < $identation) {
            $data['children'][$index]['children'] = findChild($child, $value, $identation);
            
            return $data['children'];
        } else {
            $data['children'][] = ['value' => $value, 'identation' => $identation, 'children' => []];
            
            return $data['children'];
        }
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://onlinephp.io?s=rVLBipxAED0r-A_FIKgwIXsfZ3MIgQQCuezNyNJozdig3dK2Oyth_j1V3bpjZnaXPQQcnH5V9eq91-Zf-qaPwniwRqoj7CHP82-_HqLwO07wA0QHWoHR2kYhMCRtMsBJqxrNYWwJhIdGDkDPUesarOyQQRpt9ROCbRBOYoJJjyAMelpxFFL9Qw4QhbR1F4UkpZUKB1KCz32ra0w3v9VmC7PCbLfqEMaI6bETfZoYqnYJtbma69KjpZ6i5P_SoqHDndtw0AZF1aQzjxggNvoE-3s_ncEfZwFi5uyw_kkgDfPJz2SOhlvkAVIS1qKaK_AJlvNqOoP9nra_MAeLIF68WzASXDBQsuzkSbQjJk7VimkLiaxRWWGlVq56R1DVyLY26IGiLBfKSisr1Yjz-exfszu3jnWUxYWAdx-kqr8ykK56tlcyPuKaczpzVFg1GjZ5b_B-Q1hPN2kfjaPnnrn8eanTFY2qYocrLe6yIa6FFaTFpbMF4oH4EogLOOBLwa63U-q61-4y3xHcFIqb0OcN13Gvtr0efBAYtKNRcLODixRHwAaDl4_wust9j-Qan906V5hV84_NebBYSyshvw3iNZ-e-p0rd_gl4TWpc-dUvOsxOAO2A74p4T9G_RExPvXzXw%2C%2C&v=8.2.9)

Comment: Hey I am on root
 Hey it's wonderful
 Hey it's wonderful2
  This is good time
   I love the way you are
Hey again I am on root  -- "This is good time" and "i love the way you are" should come under newly added indent which is Hey it's wonderful2